# Append a numpy.array to a certain numpy.array stored in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have been for hours strugling to understand why i am not able to do this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [np.empty((0,78,3)) for i in range(2)]
>>> b = np.random.randint(10,size=(1,78,3))
>>> a[0] = np.append(a[0],[b],axis=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 5003, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
>>>
```

`a` is a list with s empty numpy arrays of shape (0,78,3)

`b` is a random numpy.array with shape (1,78,3)

I then try to append `b` to `a[0]`... but this doesn't seem to be possible because of not having same dimension?.. I am not sure whats the problem here.. if I removed the list part it would work, so why not with the list?..

Comment: just remove the [] from b when appending. `a[0] = np.append(a[0],b,axis=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stay away from `np.append`.  Learn to use `np.concatenate` correctly.  This append just creates confusion.

Given your definitions, this works:

```
In [20]: a1 = [np.concatenate((i,b),axis=0) for i in a]
In [21]: [i.shape for i in a1]
Out[21]: [(1, 78, 3), (1, 78, 3)]
In [22]: a
Out[22]: 
[array([], shape=(0, 78, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 78, 3), dtype=float64)]
In [23]: b.shape
Out[23]: (1, 78, 3)
In [24]: a1 = [np.concatenate((i,b),axis=0) for i in a]
In [25]: [i.shape for i in a1]
Out[25]: [(1, 78, 3), (1, 78, 3)]
```

A (0,78,3) can concatenate on axis 0 with a (1,78,3) array, producing another (1,78,3) array.

But why do it?  It just makes a list with 2 copies of `b`.

```
c = [b,b]
```

does that just as well, and is simpler.

If you must collect many arrays of shape (78,3), do

```
alist = []
for _ in range(n):
   alist.append(np.ones((78,3)))
```

The resulting list of n arrays can be turned into an array with

```
np.array(alist)   # (n, 78, 3) array
```

Or if you collect a list of (1,78,3) arrays, `np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)` will join them into the (n,78,3) array.

Answer (score 0):

Your're not appending `b` but `[b]`. That doesn't work.

So in order to append `b`, use

```
a[0] = np.append(a[0],b,axis=0)
```