# Why is the array in the list not getting bigger?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am currently trying to append `numpy.arrays` to a `numpy.array` of `numpy.arrays`, but for some reason is the dimension it was supposed to increase in not increasing.

I made a prior post about the same but for `list` of of `numpy.arrays`, which worked, but since i am using way more `numpy.ndarrays` than the one in the example, i converted the list into a `numpy.arrays` to make this a bit faster - the container has the shape (72,0,78,3).

Example:

```
import numpy as np

nano_train_input = []
for i in range(974):
    nano_train_input.append(np.random.random((78,72,3)))

input_train = np.array([np.empty((0,78,3)) for i in range(72)])

print input_train.shape
raw_input("sadasd...")
#print nano_train_input.shape
i = 0
j = 0
for train in nano_train_input:
    for row in train.reshape(72,78,3):
        #print row.reshape(1,78,3).shape
        input_train[i]= np.concatenate((input_train[i],row.reshape(1,78,3)),axis=0)
        i = i+1
        print input_train[0].shape
    i=0

print input_train[0].shape
```

Problem is that after the concatenate is input_train[0].shape still (0,78,3) and not the desired (974,78,3)... how do i fix that?

I intend on converting the input_train to a list, but should be possible with `numpy.tolist()`

Comment: "but since i am using way more numpy.ndarrays than the one in the example, i converted the list into a numpy.arrays to make this a bit faster" - appending arrays one at a time is one of the few instances where you actually should stick with a list, at least until you're done appending.

Comment: `np.concatenate` doesn't actually do anything to its inputs. It builds a new array, which you ignore and discard.

Comment: Most of this code looks pretty pointless. It looks like you could just work with one array instead of a list and make a few `reshape` and `swapaxes` calls instead of trying to do any concatenation.

Comment: @user2357112 fixed it.. = still not working. I am not sure i understand why i should stick to it?.. 
If numpy does it faster?

Comment: I am not sure i understand what kind of solution your are suggesting..  
@user2357112 .. A better solution would also be better.

Comment: I recommended list appends for a reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43238729/901925